# filter from child datas field not showing any data. in MERN

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

`this is my function backend from which i am trying to get packages which is belongs to place country thailand

```
const getAllPackagesWithFilters = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const packages = await Package.find({
      "place.country": "Thailand",
    }).populate(["category", "place"]);
    console.log(packages);
    // Sort by date descending
    res.status(200).json({ status: 201, data: packages, message: "success" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ status: 500, data: [], message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

this is my package schema

```
const packageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String },
  actualCost: { type: String, required: true },
  discountedCost: { type: String },
  duration: { type: String, required: true },
  isFlightAvailable: { type: String },
  status: { type: String },
  image: { type: String },
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category", // Reference to the Category model
    required: true,
  },
  place: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Place", // Reference to the Place model
    required: true,
  },
});
```

help me out

i am getting empty array`

Comment: The `populate()` method is called after the query so when you look for a match in `place.country` the `place` property is not populated yet with documents, it still contains `ObjectId`s. You will need to take one the common alternative approaches such as using an `aggregate` query with `$lookup` or query the `places` collection and use the `place._id` value to then search `Package.place`.